# Slow text input in html field from barcode scanner

Tags: html, input, barcode

I have a webpage in my LAN in order to input barcodes in real time to a db through a field (framework django + postgresql + nginx). It works fine, but lately we have a customer that uses 72 char barcodes (Code Matrix) that slows down inputs because before next scan, user must wait the redraw of the last one in the field (it takes about 1-2 seconds, redrawing one char after the other).

Is there a way to reduce latency of drawing scanned text in the html field?
Best thing would be to show directly all the scanned barcode, not one char after the other. The scanner is set to add an "Enter" after the scanned text.

Comment: I have this issue currently in Firefox, having tested with the same barcode I get errors of a missing character in 13 of 20 scans. No issues in Chromium, no issues in a normal text editor.

Comment: Seems like the prolem is Firefox related. Try one of the fixes in this [thread](https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/1157085). Also be sure there aren't extensions that could slow up your browser. A reset to factory settings could also help to focus the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end, as Brad stated, the problem is more related to scanner's settings (USB in HID mode), although PC speed is also an issue. After several tests, on a dual core linux machine I estimate delay due 85% to the scanner and 15% to PC/browser combo.

To solve the problem I first searched and downloaded the complete manual of our 2D barcode scanner (306 pages), then I focused on **USB Keystroke Delay** as a cause, but default setting was already set to 'No Delay'.

The setting that affected reading speed was **USB Polling Interval**, an option that applies only to the USB HID Keyboard Emulation Device.

The polling interval determines the rate at which data can be sent between the scanner and the host computer. A lower number indicates a faster data rate: default was 8ms, wich I lowered to 3ms without problems. Lower rates weren't any faster, probably because it was reached the treshold where PC becomes the bottleneck.

CAUTION: Ensure your host machine can handle the selected data rate, selecting a data rate that is too fast for your host machine may result in lost data: in my case when I lowered polling interval to 1ms there were no data loss within the working PC, but when testing inside a virtual machine there was data loss as soon as I reached 6ms.

Another interesting thing is that browsers tend to respond significantly slower after a long period of use with many tabs open (a couple of hours in my case), probably due to caching.

Tests done with Firefox and Chromium browsers on old dual core PC with OS Lubuntu (linux).

Comment: Which operating system are you using and how did you set the USB polling interval?  I am looking for a way to do this on Windows 10 and have not found one.  I am quite sure that the delay for my barcode scanner is in the HID Keyboard driver because when I switch to using it as a COM interface and scan to a terminal window reading that COM port, the data transfer is so fast that I see the whole scan appear at once instantly after scanning.  In the HID Keyboard mode, it is so slow that it is like watching someone type.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has nothing to do with your page, but with the speed of the scanner interface.  Most of those scanners intentionally rate-limit their input so as not to fill the computer's buffer, avoiding characters getting dropped.  Think about this... when you copy/paste text, it doesn't take a long time to redraw characters.  Everything appears instantly.

Most of those scanners are configurable.  Check to see if there is an option on your scanner to increase its character rate.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I already studied scanner's options with no help. I know there should be a few milliseconds between the chars send via keyboard emulation, but I believe that the bottleneck is the text redraw on monitor: in fact the same scan takes less time to redraw if font is smaller or if the monitor is set to 8 bit depth.

Comment: @rospus Sounds like you don't have your graphics card drivers installed.  Text draw speed is not an issue unless something really weird is going on.  Fire up something like Notepad and see if the timing is different.

Comment: Graphic card is okay, that's its average speed. Actually it's not a big problem, input is almost immediate with normale barcodes (13-22 charts): one of our users normally reads 2-3 barcodes in a second, with the 72 chars barcodes he reads 2 barcodes every 3 seconds. I believe I could improve speed if there's a method to force not showing the 72 chars one after the other. Maybe a JavaScript that takes care of input?

Comment: Any code to handle input outside of the native browser methods will certainly be slower.  Did you do the test I suggested?

Comment: Yes, smaller font in a text editor (in my case gedit, I'm on ubuntu 12.04) displays faster.

Answer (score 0):

On Honeywell and many other brand scanners the USB Keystroke Interval is marked as an INTERCHARACHTER DELAY.

Also if there is a BAUD rate that would be something to increase.